# How to avoid a virtual function for a single derived class implementation?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I have a an `Accessor` class defining my interface to other classes and multiple base class objects within this `Accessor` class implementing stuff in various flavors.

```cpp
class Accessor
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> object1;
    std::shared_ptr<Base> object2;
}
```

The `Accessor` class implements of course more than just calls to the different objects, but there is one particular function, which indeed only redirects the function call to one of the objects.

The problem is now that this particular function is supposed to be only implemented in one derived class and when calling the function using the `Accessor` class, it is known that the particular object is always the derived class implementing this method. Currently, I'm defining an 'empty' base class method and override it only in the mentioned derived class.

However, I don't like this approach for two reasons: first, it looks ugly from the design perspective and second, I still have a `virtual` function call (and the discussed function here is in the hot path of a loop).

In summary a minimal version of the code looks as follows:

```cpp
class Base 
{ 
    virtual void f() const { std::cout << "Dummy implementation!\n";}
};
 
class Derived1 : Base
{
    void f() const override { std::cout << "Implementing the actual thing!\n";}
};

class Derived2 : Base
{
   // Carrying the dummy implementation of the base class
};

class Accessor
{
    std::shared_ptr<Base> object1;
    std::shared_ptr<Base> object2;

    // When calling this function, we know that we actually 
    // call object1 of type `Derived1`. Still, there might be 
    // cases where object1 has a different type, but then we don't 
    // call this function 
    void f() const { object1->f();}
}
```

The whole description is probably somewhat a sign that the overall design is not the best choice. However, maybe there are other options to redesign the  problem here so that the virtual function call vanishes and the code reflects the actual situation better.

Comment: *How* do you determine that you only have objects of type `Derived1` before calling the function? If there is some sort of hard guarantee you might have it as a non-virtual function only in the derived class and downcast (via `static_cast`)

Comment: I agree with UnholySheep above. Use static_cast in method f. Also consider adding assertion check to verify type for debug builds.

Comment: @UnholySheep I know that I only have objects of type `Derived1`, but the compiler doesn't know it. In the code, it is still a shared pointer to the base class. Adding assertions in order to ensure it is reasonable, indeed. I just felt like it is not necessary to describe the problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure that `object_1` always points to a `Derived1`, then make it a `std::shared_ptr<Derived1> object1`. And if the sole purpose of `Base::f()` is for `Derived1`, make it non-virtual and remove it from the classes that don't need it.

But if one of those assumptions is not true, keep it as it is:

- Making an extra test to check if the class is `Derived1` before calling a non-virtual function is not more efficient than calling directly a virtual function. If you don't trust me, make a benchmark. Moreover, if in the future you'd have a further specialization of `Derived1`, with a slightly different `f()`, you'd not have to worry.
- Assuming that it's always `Derived1` and just statically down-casting is risky.  As said, if you're so sure,  just declare it as such (go to first paragraph), and make a (safe) downcasting when you initialize `object_1`.

***Remark**:  While it may seem weird at beginning to have a `f()` that  is useless in most cases, it is in fact a common practice when using polymorphism with the [tell, don't ask](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) paradigm.  A very typical example is when using the [template method pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/template-method).*

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the base class and virtual method with `std::variant`, it is a bit slower than virtual function calls, though.
You can test if the `Derived1` type is in the `variant`.

```
    class Derived1
    {
    public:
        void f(size_t i) { ++_i; }
    private:
        size_t _i {0};
    };

    class Derived2
    {
    public:
    };

    class Accessor
    {
    public:
        template<typename S>
        void add_one (std::shared_ptr<S> val) {
            object1 = val;
        }
        // When calling this function, we know that we actually
        // call object1 of type `Derived1`. Still, there might be
        // cases where object1 has a different type, but then we don't
        // call this function
        void f(size_t i) const {
            // you can check the type with this
            //if (std::holds_alternative<std::shared_ptr<Derived1>>(object1)) {
                std::get<std::shared_ptr<Derived1>>(object1)->f (i);
            //}
        }
    public:
        std::variant<std::shared_ptr<Derived1>, std::shared_ptr<Derived2>> object1;
    };

    int main ()
    {
        Accessor obj;
        obj.add_one (std::make_shared<Derived2>());
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I was aware of the `variant` solution, but it would require to refactor the code as a whole. The answer is good, though. I just want to mention that according to the benchmarks I've seen, `std::variant` is actually faster than virtual functions.